# Subtraction operation inside jsp value =" "

Tags: jsp

I have a scenario like this, I have a text area with size limit as 250 chars.
I am displaying the no. of characters ramaining when one enters something in the text area.
Now in the edit page I want to display the no, of characters remains as 250 - the present text length in the text area.

I am trying to implement in below manner.

```
        <label for="entTypeDesc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
        <textarea name="entTypeDesc"
            onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.entTypeDesc,this.form.countdown,250);"
            onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.entTypeDesc,this.form.countdown,250);"
            id="entTypeDesc" class="form-control" path="entTypeDesc">${XXX.entTypeDesc}</textarea>
        <br>
        <font size="2">(Maximum characters: 250)<br> You have <input
            readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="250-${fn:length(XXX.entTypeDesc)}" >
            characters left.
        </font>
```

But I am getting value as 250 - 6 characters remaining.
I want it to be displayed as 244 characters displayed. So How do I do the subtraction inside value ="".

Please help. I am new in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `250-` outside of `${...}` will be interpreted as part of the String that `value=` contains.

Instead try:

```
${250 - fn:length(XXX.entTypeDesc)}
```